# how to access and write each word in string array read from a file onto a new file in c#?

Tags: c#, porter-stemmer

My testerfile contains:

```
processes
deleting 
agreed
```

And this the code in C#

```
PorterStemmer testing = new PorterStemmer();
string temp,stemmed;
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\PJM\\Documents\\project\\testerfile.txt");
System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of testerfile.txt = ");
for (int i = 0; i <2; i++)
   {
      temp = lines[i];
      stemmed = testing.StemWord(temp);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\Users\\PJM\\Documents\\project\\testerfile3.txt", stemmed);
       Console.WriteLine("\t" + stemmed);
   }
```

After running the code, the testerfile3 contains only "agre" .
So my problem here is that I want each word in the string array to be processed seperately i.e. I am having problem accessing string array. Is there any way to access every index in the string array?

Comment: As stated in the below you are over writing.  But is should have ended on "deleting".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

so each iteration in your for loop overwrites the file, and you're only left with the text from the last iteration.

you can use `System.IO.File.AppendAllText` instead

also, you can use the array's Length property to loop through all words `for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)`

Alternatively, instead of the for-loop you can use LINQ's Select to project the non-stemmed line to the stemmed one and use `AppendAllLines` to write the results:

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\PJM\\Documents\\project\\testerfile3.txt", lines.Select(l => testing.StemWord(l)));
```

Comment: working like a charm...i did not realise it was overwriting..thanks